# How to Properly Call API and Cache the Data (Node/Angular)?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, caching

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to make an API call. It only allows me to make 500 requests / 10 mins but the data returned (object with ~800 properties) only changes every few months so I rather just cache it somewhere.

I'm very new to this whole thing and I'm wondering how can I make the call every few months and store the data somewhere so that I could retrieve it from the client whenever needed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just do a duckduckgo search for "node.js caching" and you will find lots of options. As node is a running process you can just store it in RAM. Or you can use sth. like redis for better scalability. But this is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store your object for a longer period of time, I would suggest writing it to disk rather than caching it in memory (in case your node app crashes).

You didn't mention it precisely, but I assume you are referring to a simple javascript object, which you want to store? To store such an object to disk, you can do the following:

```
var fs = require("fs");

// with your object being stored in the variable "myObject", after your API call:
var myObject = ....

fs.writeFile( "myFilename.json", JSON.stringify(myObject), "utf8", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    // do whatever you want to do after file has been saved...

});
```

To read the object from disk, simply do:

```
myObject = require("./filename.json");
```